# How to Solve this Missing Index?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, indexing

I have Stored Procedure and I executed Execution Plan I have got the following Information about the Missing Index

```
/*
Missing Index Details from SQLQuery2.sql - bravo2.SFA_CAI_WP8 (PRIMASL\npremadasa (67))
The Query Processor estimates that implementing the following index could improve the query cost by 56.7627%.
*/

/*
USE [SFA_CAI_WP8]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] ([Deleted])
INCLUDE ([InvoiceNo],[NetAmount])
GO
*/
```

Therefore I have Created Non-Cluster Index as follow:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NotDeletedInvoices
ON [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] ([Deleted])
INCLUDE ([InvoiceNo],[NetAmount])
GO
```

Yet, I am getting the result of missing index....!

What should I do..?

My Stored Procedure

```
ALTER Proc [dbo].[srpInvoiceBucket]
@DistributionCenterId int
As
Set NoCount on
Begin
Begin Try
Declare @ID int,
        @Division int,
        @NumberofInvs int,
        @Numberoflooping int,
        @Maxamount money,
        @InvAmount money,
        @MinimumAmount money,
        @MaxmimumAmount money;
Declare @InvCursor Cursor
Declare @InvoiceBucket Table (ID int identity primary key, [Range] nvarchar(100), Maximum money, Minimum money, NumberofInvoice int Default(0), Total money Default(0), Average money Default(0));

-- Use Ceiling Instead of Round Due to the Issue of Rounding Value could be lower than actual Value and extra group
Select @Maxamount = Max(NetAmount), @NumberofInvs = Count(*), @Division = Ceiling(Max(NetAmount)/10) from InvoiceHeader where DistributionCenterId = @DistributionCenterId;

IF @NumberofInvs <= 0 RAISERROR (N'No Invoice Available',16,1); 
--Arranging Bucket groups
Set @Numberoflooping = 0;
While @Numberoflooping < 10
begin
If @Numberoflooping = 0 
begin Set @MinimumAmount = @Numberoflooping * @Division; end
else begin Set @MinimumAmount = (@Numberoflooping * @Division) + 1; end
Set @MaxmimumAmount = (@Numberoflooping + 1) * @Division;
Insert into @InvoiceBucket ([Range],Maximum,Minimum ) Values (Cast(@MinimumAmount as nvarchar(100)) + ' - ' + Cast(@MaxmimumAmount as nvarchar(100)), @MaxmimumAmount,@MinimumAmount )
Set @Numberoflooping = @Numberoflooping + 1;
end

Set @InvCursor = Cursor For
Select NetAmount from InvoiceHeader where Deleted = 'false'
Open @InvCursor
Fetch Next From @InvCursor INTO @InvAmount
WHILE @@Fetch_Status = 0
Begin
--Amount Bucket Opearion
Set @ID = (Select ID from @InvoiceBucket Where @InvAmount Between Minimum and Maximum);
Update @InvoiceBucket Set NumberofInvoice = NumberofInvoice + 1, Total = Total + @InvAmount Where ID = @ID;

Fetch Next From @InvCursor INTO @InvAmount
End
Close @InvCursor
Deallocate @InvCursor
Update @InvoiceBucket Set Average = Round(Total / NumberofInvoice,2) Where NumberofInvoice > 0;
select * from @InvoiceBucket;
End Try
Begin Catch
DECLARE @ErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000);
    DECLARE @ErrorSeverity INT;
    DECLARE @ErrorState INT;

    SELECT 
        @ErrorMessage = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
        @ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
        @ErrorState = ERROR_STATE();

    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState );
End Catch
End
```

Comment: Probably you should show us your stored procedure and excecution plan

Comment: May be it is asking for more Indexes.After creating this Index, see the Execution plan again.

Comment: @Jithin Shaji I have checked over and over again it shows the same

Comment: @MikkaRin I have Added the Procedure

Comment: @gayan1991 Are you sure that it is the SP procedure for which you need an index? This SP doesn't use Route_Visit_Plan_For_Day table

Comment: @MikkaRin Sorry for my mistake, I have added the correct one now

Comment: There's no index on the `MaxAmount`, `MinAmount` and `NumberOfInvoice` column of your temp table, which may slow down some selects and updates. Also, cursors are *slooooowwwwww* - maybe you should try to redesign your stored procedure to be more "SQLly", avoiding explicit loops over cursors.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, Actually Time is fine...As I tuned. Not it pops up perfectly but Missing index is still there

Answer (score 0):

I survey your stored procedure. I think that you just need following index for your stored procedure.

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index1 ON [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] ([Deleted]) INCLUDE ([NetAmount])
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX Index2 ON [dbo].[InvoiceHeader] (DistributionCenterId)
```

Comment: Thanks. However, I still get that above Index Missing Warning

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug that Microsoft has no intention of fixing in older versions of SQL Server (would have added as comment, but not enough rep). See this link:

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/400578/query-plan-missing-index-recommendation-doesnt-check-if-an-index-actually-exists